# Zend Server side validation using jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I wish to run few server side methods for validation and returning content/messages on the main page/view. But no luck so far. All I could find was running JS based validation scripts. For the start, I am looking to validate my login/registration form using ajax and server side methods. Just want to see if the user is already registered, he entered valid information..and all through php code..not JS code..any ideas?

Many thanks,
Omar

Answer (score 1):

The [`Zend_Form Quickstart`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html) pretty much covers this.

Comment: I have already created the form..just looking for the ajax based server side processing

Answer (score 0):

I got some start point from this site, really good screencasts http://www.zendcasts.com/ajaxify-your-zend_form-validation-with-jquery/2010/04/